# Что значит "жевать сопли"?

Tags: выражения

Предполагаю, что имеется ввиду склонность говорящего к пессимизму.
Или же невнятная речь?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Большой словарь русских поговорок (Мокиенко В.М.) дает несколько значений

> 1.Неодобр. Говорить невнятно.2.. Жарг. мол., Разг. Неодобр. Действовать нерешительно. 3.. Прост. Быть невнимательным, рассеянным.

Answer (score 4):

Бездействовать, откладывать 'на потOм'. To Linger

Comment: This is absolutely wrong

Comment: This is actually correct, at least one of the correct possibilities

Answer (score 2):

You can use it this way, for instance:
Прекрати жевать сопли! Будь мужиком!
Stop being a namby-pamby! Act like a man!
Stop mollycoddling!